# How to visually group class methods into sections?

Tags: python

I am a little on the pedantic side when it comes to organizing my code, so I've tried coming up with ways to visually group my class methods into logical parts/sections. My question is whether there are any **preferable ways to visually separate class method groups** in Python editors?. PEP8 doesn't mention this non-issue so I'm not sure how to do this "correctly".

I guess this desire comes from my Xcode usage where I would add `#pragma mark - XY` to separate the method sections. I'm using Sublime Text for Python, are there editors or IDEs that support a certain style of grouping?

So an example grouping that I'm currently using is to have logically similar methods one below each other but add more whitespace and a horizontal line (until it hits the 80 char border) between the "groups", like so:

```
class Foo (object):
    def __init__(self)
    
    # ------------------------- Properties
    @property
    def foo(self)
    @property
    def bar(self)
    
    # ------------------------- Querying
    def find(self, id)
    def find_siblings(self)
    def find_related(self, attr)
    
    # ------------------------- Class Methods
    @classmethod
    def setup(cls)
    @classmethod
    def purge_cache(cls)
    
    # ------------------------- Utilities
    def __str__(self)
    def __unicode__(self)
    def __repr__(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

One useful method is to use a long docstring on the class itself that logically groups the methods, see [PEP 258](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258/)

In this case you would do something like:

```
class MyClass():
   """
   This class provides a number of methods grouped accordingly:
      Methods to do with a:
       - a_do_something - Quick Summary
       - a_do_something_else - Quick Summary
      Methods to do with b:
       - b_do_something - Quick Summary
       - b_do_something_else - Quick Summary
   """
   def __init__(self):
       """ Initialise MyClass """
       pass  # More likely some code

   if True:  # Allow group folding for Functional Group A
   ## 
   ## The following functions and class methods are to do with a:
   ## 
       def a_do_something(params):
          """ Quick Summary

          Parameters:
              Describe Each
          Returns:
              What

          Long description text.
          """
          pass # really the code for this function
```

etc.

However you may wish to consider breaking any code that is long enough to need this into more classes and grouping things that way.

Comment: I'm not sure I see from that document how I would implement that into my class file, this seems to suggest how to best write docstrings for the whole class, at the top of it?

Comment: Exactly - this is the best practice - you also add more detail in each methods docstring but having grouped your class methods in the class docstring then you simply group them in the same groups in the actual class implementation.

Comment: Ah I see. That certainly helps with documentation, I'm more asking for more commonly used ways to visually separate the groups in Python editors.

Comment: Not an approved method but one that I have seen used with some success was to start each group with 'if True:  ## Group Description ******`.  The downside was that you are now indented by another level but the upside was that if you were using an editor that supports code folding then you could fold the group.  Possibly the best idea of course is that if your code is getting big enough to need such structuring then maybe it is time to refactor/sub-class the whole thing.

Comment: The `if True` is a neat hack indeed! About restructuring, it's not terribly big yet, a few hundred lines, but you're right, in Objective-C I would start using Class categories at one point.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Done!